# Invoke-WebRequest command fails only when run as script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, invoke, webrequest

I have this function in a powershell script to deploy a war file to a tomcat server.  Similar functions for the other tomcat commands (stop, undeploy, list, etc) work fine. When I run the script from a shell it works.  When I run the script from the Jenkins Powershell plugin it fails.

```
Function DeployTomcatWebApp([PSCredential]$cred, [string]$server, [string]$app)
{
    Write-Host "Deploying $app"
    $uri = $server+"/manager/text/deploy?path=/$app&update=true"
    $warpath = ($pwd).path + "/$app/build/dev/$app.war"
    $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $cred -InFile $warpath -UseBasicParsing -Verbose -Debug -Method PUT -TimeoutSec 30000 -DisableKeepAlive
    Write-Host $r.Content
    Return $r
}
```

The Console Log shows

```
Deploying DERF
D:\Jenkins\workspace\JenkinsTest_2_AD_DERF\DERF\build\dev\DERF.war
http://mytomcat:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/DERF&update=true
VERBOSE: PUT http://mytomcat:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/DERF&update=true with -1-byte payload
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At C:\Users\<jenkinsuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins1024175502034764284.ps1:49 char:10
+     $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Credential $cred -InFile $warpa ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

The Jenkins Powershell plugin extracts the script from the jenkins job and create the .ps1 file in Local/Temp and executes the script by calling

```
powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass <tempscriptname>
```

I am stumped and looking for any insight to debugging this.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

Comment: That's where I started.  Problem with that is that the with windows servers running tomcat, the undeploy may or may not work correctly.  My powershell script works around and will not start the deploy until the undeploy is successful.  I could also install a real cURL and use that.  My issue is that Invoke-Webrequest works from the command line.  It does not work from a script started by Jenkins - even though the Jenkins service is running under my account and has the same permissions and privileges

Comment: OK I see. I got around same issue by setting antiResourceLocking=true in context.xml : http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html ..